# Passing a pointer to a head pointer, void insertNode function?

Tags: c, pointers, recursion, insert, linked-list

This is a function designed to insert a new node at the end of a basic linked list.

```
node *insert(node *head, int data)
{
   if (head == NULL)
      return createNode(data);

   head->next = insert(head->next, data);

   return head;
}
```

How can I modify it so that it has no return value and instead passes a pointer to the head
pointer? Is it possible to write it recursively as above?

Here is the function signature:

```
void insert(node **head, int data)
```

Comment: `if (*head == NULL) *head = createNode(data);`, etc...

Comment: Also, `insert(&(*head)->next, data);`

Comment: Thanks, I was missing that '&' symbol in the recursive call.

Comment: You're welcome, I've made an answer out of my comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
void insert(node **head, int data)
{
   if (*head == NULL)
      *head = createNode(data);

   insert(&(*head)->next, data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Non-recursive version:

```
void insert(node **head, int data)
{
    node *p;

    if (*head == NULL) {
        *head = createNode(data);
        return;
    }
    for (p = *head; p->next != NULL; p = p->next)
        ;
    p->next = createNode(data);
}
```

Jim Balter's suggestion:

```
void insert(node **head, int data)
{
    for (; *head != NULL; head = &(*head)->next)
        ;
    *head = createNode(data);
}
```

Comment: @KeithNicholas Please explain.

Comment: it won't iterate through the list to find the empty spot and create a node

Comment: @KeithNicholas Why would it when it can insert into the first place and shift the rest of the list?

Comment: @KeithNicholas That's an extra requirement, it's not mentioned here.

Comment: "This is a function designed to insert a new node at the end of a basic linked list."

Comment: The point of the function is to add a node to the end of the list, not the beginning.

Comment: Damn it, I missed that part.

Comment: You can avoid the special test for `*head` by making `p` a `node**`.

Comment: Note that the code is now logically identical to the recursive version, which has one test, one (recursive) iteration, and one createNode ... `p` simply takes the place of the various values of `head` as it's passed down the recursive chain, so it should have the same type. ... In fact, you don't even need `p`, you could just change `head`.

Comment: @JimBalter Yes, but it only needs one stack frame to execute.

Comment: Uh, yes, that makes it iterative rather than recursive ... but in tail-recursive languages, the recursive version would be converted to the iterative version by the compiler.